# Not able to click an element present under LinearLayout in the Appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I want to click the country on Country code page while registering.
However, I have tried every `findbyElement` method i can to click the element, but it always result in

> No Such Element Error.

Can anybody please help me in that.

PS: I have used `xpath`, `ID` and `List`. But its not working, If you have any idea from the tried methods, please do share as I am new to Appium and can be wrong.
Thanks

#### screenshot

[Dumpfile screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Be47ewav5YKOwcMR6M07QRiwb2KtNGuz)
[DumpfileforUIautomator](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o5ZaTJb7mQJ2OXJN1yMptsPk7zjQxkxz)

[image: Please see the screenshot]

[image: Checkbox selected screenshot]

Comment: Try driver.findElement(By.id("asdf")).sendKeys("USD");

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using `xpath` or `name`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='India']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.Name("India")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(new By.ByName("India")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index='2']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Al Imran, but neither of the above codes seems working:

Using Xpath, this error is appearing:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)


And Using the other 2, gives:

Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator

Comment: What about By name ?

Comment: Also can you try by using index !

Comment: I have tried using Index also, Its not working.
Is it due to the complex structure created by dev for the page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that You are locating wrong control, You should be targeting radio-button/check-box control, not label next to it.

Try locating that control, not label.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("CheckBox Locator")).click();
```

try one of this solutions:

```
List<MobileElements>  listElement = driver.findElements(By.id("com.bondevalue.BondEvalue:id/country_rb"))

System.out.println("Size: " + listElement.size());
```

and then check out if this is returning any result. If it does than elements are found.

Than You have to find parent layout `com.bondevalue.BondEvalue:id/listlayout` and find every in list, and find child elements (checkboxes) like shown, and when found desired element by text (`com.bondevalue.BondEvalue:id/labelk`) then click on check box (`com.bondevalue.BondEvalue:id/country_rb`).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Kovacic, I have tried locating radio button, Text Field as well as Whole Linear Layout for that row. But nothing is working.
It always shows:
No Such Element.

Even the Done button is not working on that UI.
I desperately need this to work.

Comment: Could You please provide in question, dom of selected screen, like in screenshot but in text.

Comment: I can provide you the dump and Screenshot file of UIAutomator. it would be much more efficient

Comment: Good. Share it to be open.

Comment: Sorry, Its open now. Can you please look into it. Thanks

Comment: The size prints as zero. :(
I did this earlier too.

Comment: @Kovacic you are correct, the OP just needs to post another screenshot with the "checkbox" control selected and use its resource-id.  I cannot access his other link from my office, only the first link.  Should be that simple.

Comment: @BillHileman I have uploaded a screenshot, with checkbox selected.Could you please help me now with the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of the checkbox control, it looks like the resource id is -not- unique, which is probably why the element is designated as NAF (not accessible friendly).

Therefore, I would instead access the textview immediately following it, then use preceding-sibling to access the desired checkbox:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='+91']/preceding-sibling::android.widget.CheckBox"))
```